# How do I list all files within a set list of subdirectories in the main directory?

Tags: list, file, batch-file, cmd, directory

For Example:  List all files in the subdirectory with "121." in the subdirectory name.

This code:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*121.*) do echo %%a >> get_dirs.txt
```

Will output the folders I am looking for, but once that is set, I wish to only look in "get_dirs.txt" file list to get the files from the directories in that list. I searched all over and could only find how to list ALL files in every subdirectory, but in cases where there is > 10,000 files, the process can become slow.

Thanks in advance. If I could just have 1 output file that would be a bonus.

Comment: why not `dir /s *\*121*.* > get_dirs.txt`? no need for a for loop.

Comment: I get the following error: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
  (for /r /d %%a in (*121*) do for %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do echo "%%~fb")>output.txt
```

For each folder with 121 in its name, for each file inside that folder, echo the full path to the file

Comment: That is exactly the intent I am going for, so how would I get that written as a text file output?

Comment: It is just not working out for me. A file gets generated, however nothing gets written to the file, though I know that there are files in the folder.

Comment: @BillyD, Sorry, my fault. Corrected now (a `b` where it should be a `a`) and added the redirection code.

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you so much! If I wanted output without quotes then I just replace "%%~fb" with %%~fb (no quotes).  This solves it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%h in ('for /d %%a in (*121.*^) do @echo %%a') do dir %%h
```

should get you your directory-lists.

---

You'd get that error if there is an empty directory with a name containing `121.`

This should fix it:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%h in ('for /d %%a in (*121.*^) do @echo %%a') do IF EXIST "%%h\*" dir %%h
```

Note the `@` before the `echo` in the `for /d...` - ensures that the output of `for/d` only contains required lines, not a prompt...

Comment: THank you for the swift response, however I get a "FILE NOT FOUND" error. I would like to get the files in the directory that has the "121." string found within the name.

Comment: There is definitely a directory with 121 in the name with files in it, but it comes up with "file not found". Also, I would like the text file output with just the full path(s) of the individual files, and not volume info in it. I appreciate your time on this.